# Partial deserialization XmlArray in SOAP response .NET

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I have problem with deserialize SOAP response. I get xml like:
https://pastebin.com/pNFmJUzB
its xml from web service

But elements from RegistryObjectList is not deserialized (statusField deserialized correctly) :
[image]

This code is generated from wsdl shared by webService provider. I used svcutil to reach it. its my code :

I run this function:

```
    Public Function DocumentRegistry_RegistryStoredQuery(ByVal AdhocQueryRequest As AdhocQueryRequest) As AdhocQueryResponse
        Dim inValue As DocumentRegistry_RegistryStoredQueryRequest = New DocumentRegistry_RegistryStoredQueryRequest()
        inValue.AdhocQueryRequest = AdhocQueryRequest
        Dim retVal As DocumentRegistry_RegistryStoredQueryResponse = CType(Me,ObslugaEdmIti18WSPortType).DocumentRegistry_RegistryStoredQuery(inValue)
        Return retVal.AdhocQueryResponse
    End Function
```

which return AdHocQueryResponse :

```
'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.8.3928.0"),  _
System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true, [Namespace]:="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0")>  _
Partial Public Class AdhocQueryResponse
   Inherits RegistryResponseType
   
   Private registryObjectListField() As IdentifiableType
   
   Private startIndexField As String
   
   Private totalResultCountField As String
   
   Public Sub New()
       MyBase.New
       Me.startIndexField = "0"
   End Sub
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order:=0), _
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Identifiable", IsNullable:=False)> _
   Public Property RegistryObjectList() As IdentifiableType()
       Get
           Return Me.registryObjectListField
       End Get
       Set(value As IdentifiableType())
           Me.registryObjectListField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType:="integer"),  _
    System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute("0")>  _
   Public Property startIndex() As String
       Get
           Return Me.startIndexField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.startIndexField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType:="integer")>  _
   Public Property totalResultCount() As String
       Get
           Return Me.totalResultCountField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.totalResultCountField = value
       End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

AdHocQueryResponse Should contains ExtrinsicObjects :

```
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(RegistryObjectType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(NotificationType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(AdhocQueryType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(SubscriptionType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(FederationType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(RegistryType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(PersonType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(UserType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(SpecificationLinkType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ServiceBindingType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ServiceType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(RegistryPackageType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(OrganizationType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ExtrinsicObjectType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ExternalLinkType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ClassificationSchemeType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ClassificationNodeType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(AuditableEventType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(AssociationType1)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ExternalIdentifierType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ClassificationType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ObjectRefType)),  _
System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.8.3928.0"),  _
System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0")>  _
Partial Public Class IdentifiableType
   
   Private slotField() As SlotType1
   
   Private idField As String
   
   Private homeField As String
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Slot", Order:=0)>  _
   Public Property Slot() As SlotType1()
       Get
           Return Me.slotField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.slotField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType:="anyURI")>  _
   Public Property id() As String
       Get
           Return Me.idField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.idField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType:="anyURI")>  _
   Public Property home() As String
       Get
           Return Me.homeField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.homeField = value
       End Set
   End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(NotificationType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(AdhocQueryType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(SubscriptionType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(FederationType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(RegistryType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(PersonType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(UserType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(SpecificationLinkType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ServiceBindingType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ServiceType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(RegistryPackageType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(OrganizationType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ExtrinsicObjectType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ExternalLinkType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ClassificationSchemeType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ClassificationNodeType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(AuditableEventType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(AssociationType1)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ExternalIdentifierType)),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(ClassificationType)),  _
System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.8.3928.0"),  _
System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0")>  _
Partial Public Class RegistryObjectType
   Inherits IdentifiableType
   
   Private nameField As InternationalStringType
   
   Private descriptionField As InternationalStringType
   
   Private versionInfoField As VersionInfoType
   
   Private classificationField() As ClassificationType
   
   Private externalIdentifierField() As ExternalIdentifierType
   
   Private lidField As String
   
   Private objectTypeField As String
   
   Private statusField As String
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order:=0)>  _
   Public Property Name() As InternationalStringType
       Get
           Return Me.nameField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.nameField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order:=1)>  _
   Public Property Description() As InternationalStringType
       Get
           Return Me.descriptionField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.descriptionField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order:=2)>  _
   Public Property VersionInfo() As VersionInfoType
       Get
           Return Me.versionInfoField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.versionInfoField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Classification", Order:=3)>  _
   Public Property Classification() As ClassificationType()
       Get
           Return Me.classificationField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.classificationField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ExternalIdentifier", Order:=4)>  _
   Public Property ExternalIdentifier() As ExternalIdentifierType()
       Get
           Return Me.externalIdentifierField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.externalIdentifierField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType:="anyURI")>  _
   Public Property lid() As String
       Get
           Return Me.lidField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.lidField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType:="anyURI")>  _
   Public Property objectType() As String
       Get
           Return Me.objectTypeField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.objectTypeField = value
       End Set
   End Property
   
   '''<remarks/>
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType:="anyURI")>  _
   Public Property status() As String
       Get
           Return Me.statusField
       End Get
       Set
           Me.statusField = value
       End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

I hope that I shared all code which is needed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0")]
        public AdhocQueryResponse AdhocQueryResponse { get; set; } 
    }
    public class AdhocQueryResponse
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "RegistryObjectList", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ExtrinsicObject", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0")]
        public ExtrinsicObject[] ExtrinsicObject { get; set; }
    }
    public class ExtrinsicObject
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0")]
        public Slot[] Slot { get; set; }
    }
    public class Slot
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "ValueList", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0")]
        public string[] Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```